# Java Exception throw object and get object from catch

Tags: java

I want to pass object while getting exception and getting from catch.
I have `UserDataException` extend from Exception

```
throw new UserDataException("Media uploaded failed",mediaDO, dupkExp);
```

`mediaDO` is object.

if possible to get this `mediaDo` object from `catch` statement

```
catch (UserDataException uExp) {

    }
```

`UserdataException` calss :

```
public class UserDataException extends Exception {

private static final String ERROR = "Database Transaction Error: ";
private static final String DKERROR = "Duplicate Key Error";

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6209976874559850953L;

/**
 * 
 */
public UserDataException(String message, Throwable throwable) {
    super(message, throwable);
}

public UserDataException(String message) {
    super(message);
}

/**
 * <code>UserDataException</code> thrown with message and throwable object
 * 
 * @param schdulerData
 * @param message
 * @param throwable
 */
public UserDataException(String message, SchedulerData schdulerData, final Throwable throwable) {

    super(ERROR + message, throwable);
}

/**
 * <code>UserDataException</code> thrown with message and throwable object
 * 
 * @param schdulerData
 * @param message
 * @param throwable
 */
public UserDataException(String message, MediaDO mediaDO, final Throwable throwable) {

    super(DKERROR + message, throwable);
}
```

}

Please help if possible..

Comment: U could provide a getter method inside the exception class..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to store a reference to that object in your exception class and use a getter to get it :

```
private MediaDO mediaDO;

public UserDataException(String message, MediaDO mediaDO, final Throwable throwable) {
    super(DKERROR + message, throwable);
    this.mediaDO = mediaDO;
}

public MediaDO getMediaDO()
{
    return mediaDO;
}
```

Then in the catch block :

```
catch (UserDataException uExp) {
    MediaDO mediaDO = uExp.getMediaDO();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there any recommendation to do or not to do this ? I mean is it a good practice to do this, pass back big objects in throwing exceptions.

Comment: You can. But you must ensure that you won't throw exceptions every now and then until it is really exceptional.